# How to change network configurations, in my case, i want to change Gateway IP Address

Tags: networking

my Name is Kamunge, i am trying to make changes for the gateway and have tried all the ways including deleting all the wired connections since its static and restarting the computer having the Ethernet cable plugged out of the machine, and after writing route -n on the terminal its still showing me the former gateway configurations even not having reconfigured again.

Please Help!!!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to go to Menu --> Settings --> Network connections and click on the wired interface you are changing then click edit. In here you want to click on ipv4 then setup its IP address, network mask and default gateway.